# Расположение 2 span элементов на одной строке

Tags: css

Есть 2 span элемента внутри div, находящихся на одной стоке.

Ширина div фиксирована, ширина первого и второго span'а может меняться.
Причем их суммарная ширина может превышать ширину div блока.

Как расположить элементы так, чтобы второй span не обрезался и показывался полностью на всю ширину справа, а первый span занимал оставшуюся ширину внутри div.

Получилось сделать вот так, но никак не получается расположить их на одной строке: http://jsfiddle.net/5aq6dvhf/

```
.container {
   width:200px;
}
.left {
   float: left;
   border:1px solid;
   display: inline-block;
   overflow:hidden;
   max-width: 135px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.right {
   border:1px solid;
   display: inline-block;
   float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 135px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.right {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="left">Some text 1 Some text 1</span>
  <span class="right">Some text 2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Отлично, спасибо большое.